# External function definition to validate in Domain Class

Tags: grails, groovy

My validation looks like:

```
static constraints =
{
   someProperty validator: { val, obj ->

      // a lot of code here

   }
}
```

How can I define external function which will pass to this validation (val, obj requierd) ?
Now my code isn't clear in constraints closures... there's too much validation code for someProperty.
How can I change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I externalize a custom constraint in Grails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421204/how-can-i-externalize-a-custom-constraint-in-grails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a groovy class in the src/groovy directory, like :

```
public class CustomValidators {
    static validateMe = { val, obj ->
        // a dummy example...
        return val < 1
    }
}
```

Then, on your domain class use it like below :

```
static constraints =
{
    someProperty validator: CustomValidators.validateMe
}
```